# You did not sign in correctly or Your account is temporarily disabled Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I have try this Solution but its not working....
   Please give me suggestion to how to resolve this
   When trying to login to the admin account in my local test setup it says: Account is temporarily disabled even I used correct user and password.

**Solution 1:** Unlock admin account
try command in case the account is locked

```
php bin/magento admin:user:unlock
```

Or go to Magento 2 root folder and type

```
php bin/magento admin:user:unlock
```

**Solution 2:**
Remove Cache `var/cache`

**Solution 3:**
Remove everything, except **.htaccess** file from `pub/static` folder
Open up `app/etc/di.xml` find the path

> Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink

and replace to

> Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy

Answer (score 0):

The command `php ./bin/magento admin:user:unlock <your-username>` should work to unlock the account.

If that does not work connect to your database and check the **`admin_user`** table.

Find the user that is locked and make sure that the **`is_active`** column is set to **`1`**
[image: dbrow]

You can also try to truncate the admin sessions table `admin_user_session`

Last, if none of those work, just create a new admin with the `php ./bin/magento admin:user:create` command. Run it with `-h` at the end to see the required options.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can create new admin account then use that account to reset admin password with this syntax ([reference source](https://magentip.com/how-to-fix-you-did-not-sign-in-correctly-or-your-account-is-temporarily-disabled-in-magento-2/)):

```
bin/magento admin:user:create --admin-firstname="magentip" --admin-lastname="demo" --admin-email=magentip@gmail.com --admin-user=magentip --admin-password=Qwe@123456
```

Change the following information

-admin-user: Your admin username

-admin-password: new password (should be at least 7 letters with upper+lower cases, number,  symbols)

-admin-email: your admin email

-admin-firstname: first name

-admin-lastname: last name

success output:

```
Created Magento administrator user named magentip
```